# Is this scrollable UI design based on multiple TImages wrong for Android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Using Delphi 10.2.3 I am designing a vertical scroll list that includes:

1 x TVertScrollBox parent.
1 x TRectangle Background with a gradient fill covering the entire height of the TVertScrollBox parent.
1 x TImage "load more" button background.
1 x TLabel "load more" button text (with shadow effect).

And 5 "entries" where each entry has:

1 x TImage background image (with shadow effect).
1 x TImage displaying a thumbnail.
2 x TImage representing actions.
4 x TLabel with displaying text (1 with a shadow effect).

On windows it works well.
On Android, with nothing else running in the background, scrolling stutters and lags to the point it's not usable (tested on multiple devices).

From experimenting, I noticed that when an effect comes into view, it seems to lag and stuttering, especially on lower end devices.

Is this type of UI design simply not practical on Android using Delphi?

**Edit:**
Disabling all effects fixes this issue.

**Edit2:**
After more investigation, it appears there are two issues:
1. If there's an effect (e.g. TShadowEffect) on a TImage, scrolling will lag just once as the control scrolls into view. On later scrolls it doesn't lag anymore.
2. If the effect is on a TLabel then it will lag each time the TLabel enters into view.

Comment: Gradient, shadows... try simplifying your design. Also it is possible to patch FMX and optimize most problematic parts as explained in [Optimizing ARC - weakness of weak](https://dalijap.blogspot.com/2018/03/optimizing-arc-weakness-of-weak.html) and [Optimizing ARC with unsafe references](https://dalijap.blogspot.com/2018/01/optimizing-arc-with-unsafe-references.html)

Comment: `TControl` iterations in `FMX.Controls` unit can be easily optimized without breaking the unit interface section and all you need to do is copying that unit into your project folder and make appropriate changes. You can get from "no scrolling" to "it scrolls" in one afternoon.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Patching FMX.Controls is a bit above my capabilities, I am also not sure if it will even fix the problem since the problem is not the speed at which these components are created but rather the speed the TVertScrollBox scrolls after the components are already created.

Comment: Optimizing iterations is dead simple. Take look at following QP report [Optimize RTL and FMX frameworks for ARC - iterating through collections](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19924) There is example from TControl.PaintChildren.

Comment: Another, but more complex approach would be caching controls into bitmaps. And instead of rendering the whole control each time it comes into the visible area, you would just use pre-cached image.